# Powershell script to access MySql cloud DB

Tags: mysql, windows, powershell, cloud

I am new to shells scripting. I need to do a poc where I need to access mysql cloud database from my windows machine and query a table using power shell script?
I tried to google but was not able to check if we can access mysql cloud database from powershell script. Can you please provide me links to refer for this requirement.

Comment: I find it somewhat weird (and possibly cruel) that you were tasked with this having no knowledge wether it can be done or not in the first place. For what it's worth however, it doesn't sound like something impossible. You might wanna define 'cloud' also.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need the mysql driver installed in the machine you are running this from, then you can do this:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand ($query, $Connection)
$DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter ($Command)
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
[void]$dataAdapter.Fill( $dataSet)
$Connection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0]
```

the $ConnectionString variable should look like this:

```
 $ConnectionString = "server={your_host};port=3306;uid={username};pwd={password};database={db_name}"
```

and the $query variable would be a string with your query, like:

```
$query = "select * from mydb.myTable;"
```